# Pass large amout of data between PHP and Perl

Tags: php, perl, ipc

I have a perl script that performs operations on a large amount of data and builds a table.  I want to call upon this script from PHP.  I am passing tabular data which contains strings, quotes, and all kinds of nastyness so a simple

```
 passthru('./path/to/pl $var1 $var2');
```

won't do.  I was thinking of JSON encoding the data then base64 encoding the JSON and passing like:

```
 passthru('./path/to/pl "$base64edJSON"');
```

Is this a proper way or is there a better way?  The perl script must return the completed table back to the PHP script through a return, stdout, or some other means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the perl script using [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). Then you can feed the input to it through stdin and get the output/errors from stdout.  The Perl script will run as a pipe.

This gets around any messiness with temporary files.

Answer (score 1):

On the PHP side, [open a bidirectional pipe](http://php.net/proc_open) to the Perl process and write into its pipe. On the Perl side, read from STDIN.

To return the data, write to STDOUT in Perl. In PHP, read from the pipe.

You need no encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I would serialize the contents from PHP to a file and then load it into Perl. You can use the CPAN module [PHP::Serialization](http://p3rl.org/PHP%3a%3aSerialization).

Comment: How would I do the passing?  Just as a serialized string as in  passthru('./path/to/pl "$serializedStr"');  What about spaces, quotes, and other mess?

Comment: I hate writing to the disc if I don't have to